# SQL Server joins. please i want answer for this

Tags: sql

**Question**: when joining more than 2 tables, what rules are true?

1. All tables must be related to each other.
2. Every table must be related to at least one table.
3. A table does not have to be related.
4. There must be one table that is directly related to all other tables.

**Question**: when using a join, which option is true about the joining columns in each table.

1. Must have the same name
2. Must have the same data type
3. Must have the same name and data type
4. Must have a PK FK relationship.
5. Must have been joined in the past.

Comment: Q1: no/no/yes/no Q2:no/yes/no/no/no

Answer (score 0):

SQL offers multiple types of joins. One of the is the `CROSS JOIN`. The `CROSS JOIN` does not use any columns at all. Hence, requirements on columns are irrelevant.

If we limited the logic to `INNER JOIN` (which is a stretch given the wording), then the only conditions that must be true is (2) in the first set.